# How can I pass the value on onchange to another onchange event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var country;
  $('#selectCountry').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var country= this.value;
  });

  $('#selectedPlace').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var place = this.value;
    console.log(country);
    console.log(place);
  });
});
```

I want to get the `selectedCountry` value when I select a place or when `selectPlace` onchange event was triggered.
I tried that code but, `country` is undefined

How can I assign value on global variable from onchange event?
Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: Define country outside your onchange event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly get value of `country` when `selectedplace` `onchange` is fired

```
$('#selectedPlace').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var place = this.value;
    console.log( $('#selectCountry').val());
    console.log(place);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var country;
  $('#ddlCountry').on('change', function (e) {
     country= $('#ddlCountry').val()
  });

  $('#ddlPlace').on('change', function (e) {
    var place = $('#ddlPlace').val();
    console.log(country);
    console.log(place);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlCountry">
  <option value=0>Select</option>
  <option value=India>India</option>
  <option value=Usa>Usa</option>
</select>
<select id="ddlPlace">
  <option value=0>Select</option>
  <option value=Mumbai>Mumbai</option>
  <option value=Colorado>Colorado</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var country
      place;

 $('#selectCountry').on('change', function (e) {
  country = $('#selectCountry').val();
});

 $('#selectedPlace').on('change', function (e) {
 var place = $('#selectedPlace').val();
 console.log(country);
 console.log(place);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `var` from  `var country= this.value;` inside your  `$('#selectCountry').on('change', function (e) { });` function. just set as Global.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var country;
  $('#selectCountry').on('change', function(e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    country = this.value;
  });

  $('#selectedPlace').on('change', function(e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var place = this.value;
    console.log(country);
    console.log(place);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectCountry">
  <option value=0>Select</option>
  <option value=A>A</option>
  <option value=B>B</option>
</select>
<select id="selectedPlace">
  <option value=0>Select</option>
  <option value=a>a</option>
  <option value=b>b</option>
</select>
```